# Infinite universe and the impossibility of monochromatic light and infinite plane waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, cosmology, electromagnetic-radiation, laser

I recently [asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535680/141502) a question relating to this excerpt from the textbook *Optics*, fifth edition, by Hecht:

> Mathematically, the plane wave extends out to infinity in all its directions, and, of course, physically that cannot be. A real "plane wave" is a finite thing that, no matter how big, only resembles a mathematical plane. Since lenses and mirrors and laser beams are all finite, that "resemblance" is usually good enough.

Specifically, I asked why this was not possible.

Thinking about this further, it seemed to me that this situation is similar to that of the impossibility of monochromatic light, no? And I had actually [asked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489442/141502) a question precisely about this in the past.

Furthermore, in my now deleted comment to the [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/535687/141502) by user "Semoi", I said that, given that the empirical evidence suggests that the universe has zero spatial curvature and is therefore infinite ([assuming it has a trivial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_of_the_universe)), I do not see why Semoi's argument relating to infinite space is valid. In fact, would this evidence not suggest that plane waves *can indeed* extend out to infinity?

But if the universe is indeed infinite, then does this not also mean that monochromatic light is possible and exists in the universe?

Now, as the user "anna v" said in her [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/489446/141502), when we observe the universe, we do **not** see any evidence of monochromatic light, right? So, presuming that we have technology that should be able to detect such things, it seems to me that this suggests that monochromatic light and infinite plane waves do not exist and/or are impossibilities, right?

But then, by the same reasoning, shouldn't monochromatic light and infinite plane waves exist, or at least be possible, in an infinite universe? So does this in turn suggest that, despite the empirical evidence, that the universe is not infinite?

As you can see, the more I thought about this, the more, what seems like, contradictions I encountered, and the more questions arose. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to give me an answer to these questions that makes sense and puts my mind at ease once and for all.

Comment: That book isn't about cosmology, and probably the author is talking about what we can observe in our life. It has no information on the shape of the universe, and it doesn't try to convey anything about that. He is just suggesting that we've never been able to observe or create an infinite plane wave.

Comment: @EColnaghi My question is more general than that.

Comment: You question seems to be missing two points. One is that the infinite universe is a concept with no physical meaning. Nothing infinite can be a physical observable. The mathematical definition of infinity (if you are lucky to find a valid one) does not translate to any physical reality. Regardless, the second point is that a plane wave carries no energy. Intuitively, it is the light from a star at the infinite distance, so it’s energy is exactly zero. In this sense the plane wave also has no physical meaning.

Comment: @safesphere Hmm, interesting. So, by the same reasoning (that is, that nothing infinite can be a physical observable), can we conclude that monochromatic light cannot be observed? I'm totally happy to see an answer that explains why my assumptions don't make sense; after all, I'm just here to learn from people more knowledgeable than myself.

Comment: "*can we conclude that monochromatic light cannot be observed?*" - Correct. Please keep in mind that you may hear different opinions on infinity and the infinite universe. Although my second point should be pretty mainstream. I hope you get a full answer. Good luck!

Comment: @safesphere thanks for taking the time to add input!

Comment: Several of the answers in the linked question (and the question it was closed as a dupe of) say that an absolutely monochromatic wave is *eternal*. But our universe isn't eternal, so it cannot contain such a thing. A perfect eternal sine wave $y=A\sin(2\pi ft)$ has a single frequency $f$ in its spectrum. But if you take a finite segment of that eternal wave, then the finite segment has additional frequencies in its spectrum. You can read about that here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage That article is fairly technical, but hopefully it isn't too confusing.

Comment: @PM2Ring But if time began at the point of the big bang, then wouldn't an electromagnetic wave that has existed since that point be considered "eternal"? Or was it not possible for electromagnetic waves to exist at the earliest points of the big bang, and hence it monochromatic light is impossible?

Comment: No, a monochromatic wave is a mathematical abstraction which requires an eternal time frame, with no beginning or end. So any wave with a beginning &/or an end isn't perfectly monochromatic.

Comment: @PM2Ring Interesting. Thank you for the clarification.